# Iframe nomenucontext - Modify img tag after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am adding a iframe dynamically, It displays an image from a server. I need to disable the context menu for this item. In chrome I can inspect element and if I add oncontextmenu="return false" I do get the wanted affect. However I am unable to do this while the page is generated. Here is an example of the working html.

[image: Chrome code modified after page creation in inspector]

However I can not reproduce this when i frame is being created. Here is my code.

```
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        $('#secVerify').show();
        $("#popWaitLoad").modal("hide");
        imgLoading.hide();
        dvIframe.empty();

        //else load deposit data into interface
        $("#spanType").text(deposit.DepositType);
        $("#spanReference").text(deposit.Reference);
        $("#spanAmount").text("R " + deposit.Amount.toFixed(2));
        $("#spanDate").text(deposit.DateCreatedOffsetS);

        imageID = deposit.Deposit_Doc_imageID;
        var url = imageUrl + '/' + deposit.Deposit_Doc_imageID + '/false';

        var imgFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
        imgFrame.src = url;
        imgFrame.frameBorder = '0';
        imgFrame.scrolling = 'no';
        imgFrame.width = '100%';
        imgFrame.height = '100%';
        imgFrame.align = 'middle';
        imgFrame.id = "iframeImg";           

        dvIframe.append(imgFrame);
```

I have tried examples like.

```
    $("#iframeImage").contents().find("img").attr("oncontextmenu", 'return false');

        $('#iframeImage img').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            // Your code.
            return false;
        });
```

But because the img element seems to be only created is done after page load it seems to not work. I know disabling the the menu will not help much and I have explained all the other methods of obtaining the image that is still available but the client really wants this.

I have added nocontextmenu to the body tag and it works everywhere except for the iframe.

So let me clarify, My iframe is working like it should however I would like to disable the right click aka context menu on the specific iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `setAttribute` to set the attributes and targeted a container to `appendChild`.

```js
function example(){
var target = document.getElementById('container');
var element = document.createElement('img');
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://gopalshenoy.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/product_demos.jpg');
//element.setAttribute('width','100%');
//element.setAttribute('height','100%');
element.setAttribute('id','iframeImage');
element.setAttribute("oncontextmenu","return false;");
target.appendChild(element);

}
// Demo-Snippet use.
window.onload=example;
```

```html
<!-- Demo Snippet use -->
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you build more than one element using this function you might find further issues due to duplicated ID's.

> ID's are used to target a *specific* element **'*one of*'** so if you want to build multiple elements I would recommend giving them *unique* ID's.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tried what you have suggested. However if I try and add your code but it gives the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: Can you edit you question with the source code in text format rather than images? having access to the source rather than images of it would make it easier to work with. Then i will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok yeah that makes more sense to have source code. There you go hope that is what you where after.

Comment: Is this of any use to you?

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. I think my question is very poorly structured. My iframe is working and showing the correct img. The problem is that I would like to disable the rightclick menu on that iframe.

Comment: Your question is how to add oncontextmenu attribute while building the iframe. The above does exactly that. If this is an attempt to hide the path of the image, disabling right click is fine but F12 will still open the inspect element giving the client access to the source/path.

Comment: Yeah I know, But the client really wants that the right click to be disabled. I have managed to add the attribute to the iframe but this does not disable it. However if i add the oncontextmenu on the img tag in google inspector i get the result I am looking for. So i am trying to add it to the img tag in the iframe rather then on the iframe itself because that is not working

Comment: So why not create the image tag rather than an iframe? If this iframe only contains an image i can't see much point in using the iframe. I will edit my answer so you can see you don't need the iframe to display the image.

Comment: The iframe is part of a plugin that is required for zooming and rotating of the image.